# Stratified dataframe in R --> Manage empty values

Tags: dataframe, stratifiedjs

I would like to perform two column sampling on a dataframe. I am working on very small probabilities, and I have a problem on the end. Here is my methodology.

```
library(splitstackshape)

#Creation of a dataframe similar to the one I'm working on.
data1 <- data.frame(categorie_metier = sample(c("agriculteur", "artisan", "autre", "cadres", "employes", "ouvriers", "prof_int"), 429, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.14, 0.41, 0.25, 0.04, 0.10)), en_teletravail = sample(c("0", "1"), 429, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.59, 0.41)), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
        
#Creation of a dataframe to simulate my probabilities.
data2 <- data.frame(categorie_metier = sample(c("agriculteur", "artisan", "autre", "cadres", "employes", "ouvriers", "prof_int"), 1000000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.01, 0.03, 0.27, 0.21, 0.13, 0.10, 0.25)), en_teletravail = sample(c("0", "1"), 1000000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.991, 0.009)), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
        
#Grouping of columns.
data2$groupe <- paste(data2$categorie_metier, data2$en_teletravail)
        
#Extraction of groups in a variable. Objective: Create an output dataframe of 50 lines.
gsize <- 50 * round(prop.table(table(data2$groupe)), 2)
gsize = as.list(gsize)
        
#Generation of the output dataframe.
data3 <- stratified(data1, c("categorie_metier", "en_teletravail"), gsize)
Error in stratified(data1, c("categorie_metier", "en_teletravail"), gsize) : 
Incompatible sizes supplied
```

According to my research, this error is due to the existence of values ​​of 0 in "gsize". This is inevitable, because I am working on very small probabilities.
How could I handle these values ​​at 0, knowing that I cannot enlarge the size of data3 ?

Thank you.